# Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ with more than one element. Let $a \in A$. If $A\setminus\{a\}$ is compact. Then prove that $A$ is disconnected.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ with more than one element. Let $a \in A$. If $A\setminus\{a\}$ is compact. Then prove that $A$ is disconnected.

My Attempt:
We know that if $A = B \cup C$ such that $B \neq \phi$,
$C \neq \phi$ with $\overline B\cap C$ = $\phi$, $B \cap \overline C$ = $\phi$ then $A$ is called disconnected. Here $A = A\setminus\{a\} \cup \{a\}$ such that $\overline A\setminus\{a\} \cap \{a\} = \phi$
, $A\setminus\{a\} \cap \overline{\{a\}}$ = $\phi$ $\implies$ $A\setminus\{a\} \cap \{a\} = \phi$, $A\setminus\{a\} \cap \{a\}$ = $\phi$ because

$A\setminus\{a\}$ and $\{a\}$ are closed sets so $\overline A\setminus\{a\} = A\setminus\{a\}$ and $\overline {\{a\}} = \{a\}$ Am I right? Please provide me alternate proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As $A\backslash\{a\}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you know that $A\backslash \{a\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is hence closed in $A$ in the subspace topology. Also $A\backslash\{a\}$ is open in $A$ as singleton sets are closed in the subspace topology. Thus you find that $A\backslash\{a\}$ is an open and closed proper subset of $A$. Thus $A=(A\backslash\{a\})\cup \{a\}$ is a separation of $A$ into disjoint non-empty open and closed sets. Thus $A$ is disconnected.

Note: The definition of disconnectedness you gave is equivalent to the condition $A=B\cup C$ where $B,C$ are non-empty open subsets of $A$ and $B\cap C\neq \emptyset$. You can try to prove it.